# Отчего возникает ошибка компиляции else without if?

Tags: java, android

```
 if (getCheckEmailFromServer == true || getCheckNameFormServer == true || getCheckNumberFormServer == true);
        {
            Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, GiftHomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(nextActivity);
        }
        else
        {
            if (getCheckEmailFromServer == false)
            {
               emailHint.setText("You enter wrong Email. Please, try again.");
            }
            else if (getCheckNameFormServer == false)
            {
                nameHint.setText("You enter wrong name");
            }
            else if(getCheckNumberFormServer==false)
            {
                numberHint.setText("You enter wrong number");
            }

        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

В данном случае подсвечивается else, и пишет "else without if"

Comment: Точка с запятой стоит после ифа у тебя.

Comment: Спасибо, только заметил

Comment: @DanielOlivo,  оформите ответ, он же правильный

Comment: `if (getCheckEmailFromServer == true || getCheckNameFormServer == true || getCheckNumberFormServer == true);`
можно упростить, и не писать ==true, на будущее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первой стройке уберите ";" после условия if и будет вам cчастье

научитесь читать лог ошибки, там же все написано :)

Answer (score 6):

В первой строчке после конструкции if стоит ";".